# I am confused about Newton's second law $F=ma$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, speed

If I push or pull a statue at steady speed, the force, $F=ma$, would be equal to zero since I am not accelerating. Doesn't that make the quote "Force is a push or pull" not true, since there is no force, (according to the formula), despite me pushing or pulling the object?

Comment: If you can overcome statue static resistance force (which is a lot higher than yours)- then statue will move. How Do you think crane works at least? Because it can generate high enough force / torque on a massive object.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the important point that the force $F$ in Newton's law $F=ma$ is the ***net*** ***force*** acting on an object.

If you push or pull an object at steady speed it does not accelerate because there is another equal and opposite force involved making the net force on the box zero. An example is pushing a box along a floor with friction at steady speed. There is an equal and opposite kinetic friction force to yours on the box for a net force of zero. Instead of the work you do accelerating the box, the kinetic friction force takes the energy you supply to the box and dissipates it as friction heating.

The quote "Force is a push or pull" is true for any force, regardless of whether or not the force results in acceleration. For example, if you push or pull on a wall you are exerting a force on the wall. The wall does not move because the ground supporting the wall exerts an equal and opposite force on the wall for a net force of zero on the wall so that the wall does not budge.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

System: Statue

Forces on **statue**:
$\bf 1$ Vertical force downwards due to gravitational attraction of **Earth**
$\bf 2$ Vertical force upwards due to **ground**
$\bf 3$ Horizontal force due to **you** pushing/pulling
$\bf 4$ Horizontal friction force due to **ground** in opposite direction to motion of statue.

If forces $\bf 1$ and $\bf 2$ are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, and forces $\bf 3$ and $\bf 4$ are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction then the **net** force on the statue is zero and the statue does not accelerate.

Answer (score 2):

Newton's 2nd law is not $F=ma$. It is: $$\sum F=ma.$$

This is a very, very important distinction. The law does not tell what a single force does, it only tells what *the sum of all acting forces* causes. Your force individual force is pushing, but another force (normal force, I'd guess in your scenario) is holding back.

Overall they cancel out. That does not mean that your individual force never existed. Be careful never to mistaken Newton's 2nd law as applying to just one force. You might often see the law written as $$\sum F=ma \quad\text{or}\quad F=ma \quad\text{or}\quad F_{res}=ma \quad\text{or}\quad F_{total}=ma\quad\text{or}\quad F_{net}=ma$$
or similar. But all such notation still implies that we are dealing with *the sum of all forces* a.k.a. *the resultant force*. Of that reason I personally always avoid writing $F=ma$ so that I avoid mistaken the $F$ for a single force.

Answer (score 0):

It does produce an acceleration but it doesn't move as some other force might be opposing it ;for example friction ,as might be imagining pushing or pulling the object on a surface such as floor or a table.

Comment: If acceleration is produced, by definition, a change in velocity should be observed. If it doesn't move, there is no acceleration. You are confusing force, net force, and acceleration. The correct statement is: "It would produce an acceleration..."

Answer (score 0):

If the statue is on the ground there are two forces: the force you exert and the frictional force that opposes the motion. $\vec F = m\vec a$ says the net force produces acceleration.  Here, the net force is the force exerted minus the force of friction. You must exert force greater than the frictional force to start the statue moving (accelerate the statue). Once the statue is moving, if the force exerted equals the force of friction the statue has zero acceleration and moves at constant velocity; however, you must still exert force to counter the force of friction.

Answer (score 0):

The words push and pull has to do with direction of force and the biological effect from muscles of your body.